# Parse JSON data, and write the data to a file using groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Here we are replacing a value of "**dpidsha1**" from **1234** to another value "**abcd**" in json conent, and **We are trying to** **write json formatted content to a file "uselessfile.json", and print the content of the file "uselessfile.json"**

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def buildContent(){


def content = """
{
   "app":{ },
   "at":2,
   "badv":[ ],
   "bcat":[ ],
   "device":[ {
      "carrier":"310-410",
      "connectiontype":3,
      "devicetype":1,
      "dnt":0,
      "dpidmd5":"268d403db34e32c45869bb1401247af9",
      "dpidsha1":"1234" 
   },
   {
      "carrier":"310-410",
      "connectiontype":3,
      "devicetype":1,
      "dnt":0,
      "dpidmd5":"268d403db34e32c45869bb1401247af9",
      "dpidsha1":"1234" 
   }]
}"""

def slurped = new JsonSlurper().parseText(content)
def builder = new JsonBuilder(slurped)
builder.content.device.dpidsha1 = 'abcd'  
println(builder.toPrettyString())

writeFile file: 'uselessfile.json', text: builder.toPrettyString(content)

  File file = new File("uselessfile.json")

  println "Below is the content of the file ${file.absolutePath}"
  println uselessfile.json
```

**ERROR:**

[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
an exception which occurred:
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv.locals

Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.json.JsonBuilder

Comment: `jsonBuilder.toPrettyString(content)` should be `builder.toPrettyString(content)`

Comment: It still fails while writing the data to uselessfile.json file. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pipeline utility steps](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#pipeline-utility-steps) `readJSON` and `writeJSON` to archive your goal as following:

```
def buildContent(){

   def content = """
      {
         "app":{ },
         "at":2,
         "badv":[ ],
         "bcat":[ ],
         "device":{
            "carrier":"310-410",
            "connectiontype":3,
            "devicetype":1,
            "dnt":0,
            "dpidmd5":"268d403db34e32c45869bb1401247af9",
            "dpidsha1":"1234" 
         }
      }
   """

   def jsonObj = readJSON text: content.trim()
   jsonObj.device.dpidsha1 = 'abcd'

   writeJSON file: 'uselessfile.json', json: jsonObj, pretty: 4

   sh 'cat uselessfile.json'
}
```

The reason of `java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.json.JsonBuilder` is Jenkins pipeline will store the pipeline after serialize. But the class `groovy.json.JsonBuilder` not implement `Serializable`, thus it's can't be serialized

Comment: Still getting ERROR: No such field found: field net.sf.json.JSONArray version.                                                                                                                                                                                                        I have updated the question .